# I'm looking for a slightly blocky serif font for a skate/lifestyle brand

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I found [Friz Quadrata](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/friz-quadrata/) which is what was used for BlackFlag, and I really like it, but it is already being used by the company Anti Social Social Club, and don't want to look like it was completely copied.
[image]

Are there any other fonts you can recommend that have this appeal to them?

Answer (score 1):

Dragon Serial https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/softmaker/dragon-serial/heavy/ is a nice looking flair serif that I think would work with some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try Cinzel bold, or black? A little sharper than Friz Quadrata, but you can go in with illustrator and alter the letterforms as you like.